# How to solve this error in the name property of composer.json validation?

Tags: console, composer-php

I got this error as i validate my composer.json file:

```
  [Composer\Json\JsonValidationException]                                                                                                                                                                           
  "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:                                                                                                                                                        
   - name : Does not match the regex pattern ^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]?|-{0,2})[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

The name Property looks like this:

```
"name":"lukas735/united-in-faith",
```

I also tried out the following alternations:

```
"lukas735/united-in-faith",
"lukas/united-in-faith",
"lukas735/united.in.faith",
"lukas/united.in.faith",
"lukas735/united_in_faith",
"lukas/united_in_faith",
"lukas/uif",
"lukas735/uif",
```

None of this worked... The regex proofer said the forward slash is placed wrong... But its composer intern so i can't change anything on that. And anyway. My strings also not got matched if i corrected that in regex proofer.

Is there anyway to let match my united-in-faith String... The name before was just an account name  because a video said this vendor-name can be choosed yourself... But video was from 2016. I found no hints in internet where to find the vendor-name. So i choosed it myself.

I saw some videos and topics about this naming convention, but they all not seemed to giving an answer which solved it.

What did I wrong?
Has anybody a solution for this error?

Here is my Composer.json File:

```
    {
    "name":"lukas735/united-in-faith",
    "description":"description",
    "keywords": [
        "united-in-faith",
        "united in faith",
        "united_in_faith",
        "dating"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://...",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "...",
            "email": "....",
            "homepage": "...",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "repositories":[
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "lukas735/united-in-faith",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/...",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "components/jqueryui": "^1.12",
        "united-in-faith": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "lukas735\\": "sites/classes"
        }
    },
    "recommend":{
            "ext-zip":"*"
    },
    "bin":["bin"],
    "config":{
            "vendor-dir":"vendor"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "phpspec run",
        "format": "phpcbf --standard=psr2 src/"
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Composer are you using? If the same error is thrown on `"lukas/uif"`, then the problem is somewhere else in that file - have you tried to check **where** by removing other parts? Also, if your package is located on Github, you don't need to provide a `repositories` configuration - better publish it on Packagist

Comment: Composer 2.1.3. And meanwhile i found the problem... In no video was said that you have to run composer init on installation... Always wondered why i have to make the composer.json file myself. ...Now i know i don't have too.

Answer (score 0):

use command 'composer init' to make a new composer.json file, use old for reference